# How to search a line in a file which do not contain certain string ,in unix OS?

Tags: linux, string, file, search, grep

I have 32 million lines in a file and almost every line contains the string say "20112233" ,the file size is 100 MB and i want to find the line which do not contain the string "20112233" ,May be using grep or any other method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -v 20112233 filename
```

`-v` inverts the search, so gives you the lines that do not include your search string